# MySQL Result in $row will not echo in if conditional

Tags: mysql, if-statement, row

I am trying to get the row queried in preceding code to echo inside of this if conditional if the user clicks the modify video link. However, when I echo the $video variable directly above the if ($videoEdit) { conditional, it displays on page, but if I try to echo it inside the if ($videoEdit) { conditional, it will not output for some reason. I'm confused. Here is my code (query not included, but echo $video does output proper results before conditional)

Addition:::

```
require ('../mysql_connect.php'); // Connect to DB

    // Handle Video Edit
   if ($_GET['video'] == "EDIT") {

$videoEdit = TRUE;

   }

    $query = "SELECT inventory.inv_key, inventory.mdl_key, inventory.serial, inventory.date_aquired, inventory.location, inventory.price, model.mdl_key, model.man_key, model.cls_key, model.sub_cls_key, model.model, model.video, model.picture, model.pdf, subclass.sub_cls_key, subclass.subclass, class.cls_key, class.class, manufacturer.man_key, manufacturer.manufacturer FROM inventory, manufacturer, model, class, subclass WHERE inventory.mdl_key='$_GET[mdl_key]' AND model.mdl_key='$_GET[mdl_key]' AND class.cls_key='$_GET[cls_key]' AND subclass.sub_cls_key='$_GET[sub_cls_key]' AND manufacturer.man_key='$_GET[man_key]' AND manufacturer=manufacturer.manufacturer AND class=class.class AND subclass=subclass.subclass";
$result = @mysql_query ($query); // Run the query

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array 
($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$model = $row['model'];
$mdl_key = $row['mdl_key'];
$video = $row['video'];
$picture = $row['picture'];
$pdf = $row['pdf'];
$description = $row['description'];
$manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
$man_key = $row['man_key'];
}
```

Addition Above::::

```
if ($_GET['video'] == 'EDIT') { 
$videoEdit = TRUE; 
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$video = $row['video'];
}

if ($videoEdit) { // <-- boolean comparison
echo '<form action="edit_media.php" method="post">
<p>Video Link: <input type="text" name="serial" size="25" maxlength="100" value=';
       if (isset($video))
            echo $video;
        }
            echo ' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p>               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
        </form>';
}
```

Addition:: this is, in my code, directly below the above code

```
if ($video != "") {
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src=' . $video . ' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> | <a href=edit_media.php?video=EDIT&mdl_key=' . $mdl_key . '&man_key=' . $man_key . '>Modify Video Link</a>';
} else {
    echo "Video Not Present | <a href=edit_media.php?video=EDIT>Add a Video</a>";
}
```

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to let you know that you should stop using `mysql_` functions to write new code as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead. Have an outstanding day

Comment: Thanks, it's been awhile for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, `$video` is not set.

You should try to `echo $video;` after the `while` loop. Also, you should not be using a loop unless if you're only fetching a single result.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$video = $row['video'];
echo $video;
```

**Update**

Here's how I would approach your problem (obviously replacing `mysql_` functions):

```
if ($_GET['video'] == 'EDIT') { 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ... ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $video = $row['video'];

    echo '<form action="edit_media.php" method="post">
    <p>Video Link: <input type="text" name="serial" size="25" maxlength="100" value='";
    if (isset($video)) {
        echo $video;
    }

    echo '" /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p>               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
            </form>';
    }

}
```

Also noticed that you were missing the open curly bracket (`{`), and double quotes around the value of `$video` in the HTML.

Comment: I CAN echo $video and it displays the video link, outside the if conditional. but inside it, nope.

Comment: Are you sure that `$videoEdit` is true?

Comment: if ($_GET['video'] == "EDIT") {

 $videoEdit = TRUE;

}

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. when the user clicks modify video - it takes them to this page again, except the url is .php?video=edit

Comment: Also, I know it's true, because the <form> is displayed when I click Modify Video link, and that form is echo'ed inside the IF ($videoEdit == TRUE) conditional

Comment: @BiTZOiD Where does the query come in? Can you show some more code?

Comment: The page starts with the if ($_GET['video'] == "EDIT") { $videoEdit = TRUE; }  and then directly below that is the query that selects the database results. if ($result) is ok then it runs a while ($row = mysql_fetch_array) deal, and inside assigns the variable $video with the = $row['video']; . . . Then it's what you see above.

Comment: Also, I added some more of the code under the Addition:: in the original post

Comment: @BiTZOiD It seems as though you were missing an open curly bracket... see my update

Comment: Nope, I had the brackets. I've Updated again my original post to contain all important to this post.

Comment: I Think in the query it uses WHERE clause that defines $_GET patterns, that I didn't carry over in the videoEdit == TRUE conditional. Let me try

Comment: YES!!!!! That was it, I'm such an idiot. I just had to carry over, aditionally, the cls_key and the sub_cls_key in the href of the Modify Video link. NJK - You actually walked me through it and helped me discover the problem. Thanks alot, if I had money I would donate to this site. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an echo before the remainder of your html string  ' />< /p>...'

```
if (isset($video))
      echo $video;

echo ' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p> <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" /></form>';
```

Comment: Make sure you are aware that the GET variable is case sensitive. So if you have ?video=edit and you are checking for $_GET['video'] == 'EDIT' these will not be equivalent

Comment: That I did not know, thanks. However, I have all of that correct in the code already.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer, but looks like you need another "echo" before continuing the loop, after trying to echo out the $video content. Before this:

```
' /></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Video" /></p>               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
```